# How connect Jena Fuseki Server to Netbeans like MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sparql, jena, netbeans-8

I would like to connect Jena Fuseki server to netbeans and start to query sparql codes using java program. I did imported the jena libraries but, I'm stock on how to connect and make some queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run server as per documentation.

For query, use `QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`

For update, `UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote`

See javadoc and http://jena.apache.org/ for details.